# How to filter Realm Results that start with alphabetical character

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I'd like to filter Realm results in Swift to get only records which start with alphabetical character.
Using Realm Swift version 2.4.2

Initial thought was to use `MATCHES` predicate string with regex

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName MATCHES '^[a-z].*'")
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.objects(Friend.self).filter(predicate)
```

But any use of `MATCHES` predicate for Realm filtering crashes the app with error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

It works with `BEGINSWITH`, but for that all characters should be "OR"ed:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName BEGINSWITH[c] 'a' OR firstName BEGINSWITH[c] 'b' OR ... OR firstName BEGINSWITH[c] 'z'")
```

The Realm documentation tells that `MATCHES` are supported by filter - https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

So the question is: What is the best method to filter Realm results for starting with alphabetical character on Realm Swift?

Comment: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
" Could you show the whole error message?

Comment: @Larme This is additional error text that is seen on crash "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid operator type', reason: 'Operator 'MATCHES' not supported for string type'"

Comment: The [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) lists all features of `NSPredicate`. Only those denoted with a pink dot are supported by Realm.

Comment: I thought it's html issue. It is really misleading; no annotation no comment, just red dots. So the only solution still seems to be those `OR`s with `BEGINSWITH`